# Como puedo iniciar un live server con node npm?

Tags: nodejs, npm, servidor

soy nuevo en esto, quería saber como iniciar un live server con node npm? lo he iniciado con python pero no tiene live-reload, cuando lo intento con npm me salta un error

Comment: Bienvenido cual es error que te esta mostrando, edita la pregunta y agrega el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una extensión dependiendo de tu navegador [aquí](http://livereload.com/extensions/) o usar un script

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] +':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
</script>
```

Comment: Listo ya lo hice correr, muchas gracias

Comment: Listo, puedes puntuar mi respuesta como la acertada en ese caso

Comment: Y como hago aqui para aplicar ese codigo ?